# NSTableView without scrolling, instead push down content below

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autolayout, nstableview

I would like to create a `NSTableView` so that when it grows it will not scroll but instead push down the content below. The `NSTableView` and the content below will be wrapped in a `NSScrollView` that will autoresize with the windows height.

Is this even possible? I've spent a lot of time searching for any answer or even a clue on how to approach a design like this, but no luck. Should I even use a `NSTableView` for this?

See this image if you don't understand what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to calculate the total height of your all table cells and that value set as a table height. After that set your scroll view content size as a CGSizeMake(scrolviewwidth, table_height)

Answer (score 0):

Select tableView and in attributes inspector in section Scroll View uncheck `Scrolling Enabled`. It is possible, that you will have to set table height manually [viz previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21268456/1474284).